# Spring-boot api rest stops working after redeploying

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have an spring-boot project, and API-REST. When I'm hitting it with the localhost:8080/clientes it returns a json with all the client data. But when I restart the server or do a redeploy, I only get the client amount, but with no data, everything is null.

So basically it works until we change something or redeploy.

This is running on a DigitalOcean droplet. Ubuntu.

```
package com.gestion.backend.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import com.gestion.backend.entidades.Cliente;
import com.gestion.backend.services.ClientesService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class ClientesController {

    @Autowired
    ClientesService clientesService;


    // Traigo todos los clientes
    @GetMapping("/clientes")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('PM')")
    public List<Cliente> getCLientes(){
        return clientesService.getClientes();
    }

    // Traigo un usuario especifico
    @GetMapping("/clientes/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('PM')")
    public Cliente getCliente(@PathVariable Long id){
        Cliente  data = clientesService.getClienteById(id);
        System.out.println("List<Cliente>: " + data);
        return clientesService.getClienteById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/clientes")
    Cliente newEmployee(@RequestBody Cliente nuevoCliente) {
        return clientesService.saveCliente(nuevoCliente);
    }



}
```

Application properties:

```
    spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: test
    driver-class-name : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I expect the client list with all the data, but only get an empty response (all fields are null)

Comment: We will need more information. Do you use any database?

Comment: Looks like you drop DB on restart/redeploy

Comment: @michalk I'm using a mysql database, running also local.The information is in the tables but the api just throughs null fields.

Comment: I guess you are using hibernate as your JPA provider. Can you show application properties and how you configure datasource?

Comment: @michalk I'll attach the application properties on the main post.